# Add a number of buttons to view with X,Y,padding constraints using autolayout programatically

Tags: ios, xcode, button, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Let say I have a N numbers of buttons..

```
//---listOfServicesToDisplay is DYNAMIC
NSMutableArray * arrayOfButtons = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=0; i<[listOfServicesToDisplay count]; i++) {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [arrayOfButtons addObject:button];
}
```

I want to add arrayOfButtons to my superView with a constraints of:

- Center Y Alignment (Vertical)
- Center X Alignment (Horizontal)
- Leading and Trailing with 50 padding. H:|50-[BUTTON]50-|
- Top and Bottom with padding 1
- For the most Top/Bottom button its padding would be dynamic

If I do it on INTERFACE BUILDER It would be look like this..(hence that I NEED TO DO IT PROGRAMATICALLY)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this works, it sets up a wrapperView around the buttons, aligns the buttons inside this view and centers the wrapperView inside its superview.

```
UIView *buttonView = [UIView new];
[buttonView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:buttonView];

NSLayoutConstraint *horizontal = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:buttonView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:buttonView.superview
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0.0];

NSLayoutConstraint *vertical = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:buttonView
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:buttonView.superview
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                           multiplier:1.0
                                                             constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *width = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:buttonView
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:buttonView.superview
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                        multiplier:1.0
                                                          constant:-100];

// height will have to wait until we know what the buttons are up to

[buttonView.superview addConstraints:@[horizontal, vertical,width]];

CGFloat buttonHeight = 50;
CGFloat buttonSpace = 10;

NSInteger numberOfButtons = [buttons count]; // buttons = your array of buttons
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < numberOfButtons; index++) {
    UIButton *button = [buttons objectAtIndex:index];
    [buttonView addSubview:button];

    NSLayoutConstraint *width = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:buttonView
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                            multiplier:1.0
                                                              constant:0];

    NSLayoutConstraint *height = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:Nil
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:buttonHeight];

    NSLayoutConstraint *horizontal = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:buttonView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:0];

    [buttonView addConstraints:@[ width, height, horizontal]];

    // a bit clumsy here, due to the first button
    if (index == 0) {
        NSLayoutConstraint *vertical = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:button.superview
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                                     constant:0];

        [button.superview addConstraint:vertical];
    } else{
        UIButton *formerButton = [buttons objectAtIndex:index-1];
        NSLayoutConstraint *vertical = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:formerButton
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                                     constant:buttonSpace];

        [button.superview addConstraint:vertical];
    }
}

UIButton *lastButton = [buttons lastObject];
CGFloat viewHeight = (buttonSpace + buttonHeight) * [buttons count];

NSLayoutConstraint *height = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:buttonView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:nil
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:viewHeight];
[buttonView addConstraint:height];
```

Now, I haven't attempted to clean this up at all and you'd certainly don't want to have this all in one block, but the concept is sound and you should be able to achieve what you want. Personally I often use a separate class to handle constraints to avoid duplication of code.